# Is there a way to detect if the user has pressed the refresh button using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

I want to know if jquery or javascript can detect if the user has pressed the refresh button of their browser? If so can I see an example?

Comment: What are you really trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.onunload event will be fired before the page is going to be refreshed.

```
window.onunload = function(){
    alert("unload event detected!");
}
```

Comment: It's also fired when the user presses the back button, or clicks on any link. Doesn't tell you anything at all about refresh.

Comment: @roufamatic in my case, using backbone, this effectively only catches the refresh event as the browser's back button doesn't reload the page, only navigates through the backbone history. But, I think you're right in any "regular" web app.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to detect if the user pressed refresh before the page refreshes, but you can use cookies to determine if the page refreshed once it loads the second time.

For example, each page could store the `location.href` in a cookie, and if the last cookie equals the same `location.href` of the current page, then the user most likely refreshed the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that, but what you could do instead as a hacky workaround is maybe render the referring page URL from the server into a hidden input or something, and on page load, check to see if the value of the hidden div is the same as the current URL. If it is, it must be a postback or a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

there is 1 way to detect it.

check to see if F5 was pressed. as to detect if the actual refresh was clicked, that i'm not sure if its possible, but you can check against the key code

[JS Code](http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx)
[.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Comment: Presuming that F5 causes a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are looking to detect if user press F5 or ctrl+ f5 then you can use following code :)

```
$("body").keydown(function (e)
{
   if (e.which == 116 || e.which == 17) {
     inFormOrLink = true;
   }
});
```