# is there a way to find out if the http request is coming from a expired web page

Tags: java, servlets, request, servlet-filters, servlet-listeners

is there a way to find out if the http request is coming from a expired web page(IE Page which says webpage has expired). I am expiring a webpage on click of a back button. 
Now on the expired page, I do a refresh/or F5 and I want to take the user on a particular page with the error message. This particular page is my home page and request mapping is /homecontroller.
I am trying to use a filter to achieve this but I dont have a way to know if the request is coming from the expired page or the login page. Can someone please help.

Example - Suppose there are 3 pages A(/controllerA) -> B(/controllerB) -> C(/controllerC).

1. Now when I go to page B from page A, I cleared the cache by setting setCacheSeconds(0), setUseExpiresHeader(true), setUseCacheControlHeader(true), setUseCacheControlNoStore(true).
2. Now I am going to page C from page B.
3. Now I click browser back button when I am on page C so that I can go back to page B
4. Now instead of getting page B, I get "Webpage has expired" message page of IE
5. ON the above expired page, I do refresh or F5. Call goes to url (/controllerB)
6. Now in the controller of (/controllerB), I want to check if this call is coming from expired page then forward this call to /controllerA so that home page A can be displayed. If this call is not coming from expired page, I want to show the page B from the /ControllerB

Comment: What do you mean by expired page ?

Comment: Are you using cookie to track the expiry ?

Comment: Try to use attributes in the session.

Comment: Expired page means the page with the message "Webpage has expired". It comes when you clear the cache while loading the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you would need some kind of `token` (parameter) passed from page B to page C to validate that request is not expired.
This would be proposed flow:
 - on transition from A to B, you set in session attribute like 'expectedToken' = n
 - page B on transition to C, sends also this token (eg via request parameter in GET, or hidden in POST)
 - controller C, you check if `expectedToken` from request is same as in session and increment `expectedToken` in session. If token from request is the same as in session your transition is valid, if tokens didn't match then it was resend from expired page (since browser will use old token value, and you will have already incremented one in the session).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using session when user login set that username or id in session attribute

```
session.setAttribute("userid",  "21");
```

and keep session timeout in web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

when user try to access page in your filter try to validate if session is active this can be done using below code

```
session.getAttribute("userid");
```

If above code return null than redirect user to login page else allow to access your class. If session return null that it means session has expired.

To invalidate session

```
session.invalidate();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I do not want to invalidate the session.. Take an example of bank site, you click on back button and  you get webpage has expired message. Now you click on refresh in IE, you will get retry/cancel message. On Click of retry, I want to redirect the user to his personal home page or any other page for that matter.

Comment: @deepak In bank I have seen ideally if we press back button they logout us. But if you want them to take to home page then you have to catch event on f5 or try again in javascript and accordingly forward it to home page. check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741397/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-the-user-has-pressed-the-refresh-button-using-jquery)